# I need help Identifying this chess set

Tags: chess-set, identify-this

I need help identifying this chess set, I got it from my father and he says it is from Poland and on the broken board it says it is made of crystal bohemia.
[image: some of the black side paces]

[image: A black side pawn and some white side paces]

[image: The box for the game]

[image: The broken board]

Comment: Bohemia is in Czech Republic, not  Poland. It is a region which has been famous for its glass (bohemian glass) and was an independent kingdom for quite some time. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemia For more data you should post a photo with  any labels and logos you have on the set, box or board.

Answer (score 2):

The closest one that I have found is called celestial strains at:
http://www.chess-museum.com/stone--glass-sets.html

There are some Polish sets on the site but they are not the same.